¿Como instalo GDAL en Railway con python 3.11?
Tengo un servicio activo en Railway, quiero usar GeoDjango con Postgis para poder usar funciones de mapas, pero no logro instalar GDAL en el servidor de Railway.
En mi local funcion a todo correctamente, pero al momento de pasar a produccion en Railway,  no logro hacer que funcione, e intentado con dockerfiles, y apt, runtime, pero no lo consigo
Estoy usando el Template de :

Para la base de datos
Ya me asegure que POSTGIS este instalado

¿Alguien a podido instalar GDAL en Railway?
Tengo esto en mi settings.py:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.gis',
    ...
    ]

...
import os
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = os.getenv('GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH', '/usr/lib/libgdal.so')

Y en mi archivo Procfile lo siguiente:
release: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y gdal-bin libgdal-dev libheif-dev libde265-dev libx265-dev
web: python manage.py migrate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && gunicorn aetorescue.wsgi

